# how to find a prime number function in python

Tags: python, boolean, logic, primes, boolean-logic

I started getting back to python coding and realized I couldn't quite figure this out. I'm trying to code a prime number function. Could someone help with this?

Here is my code:

```
def is_prime(x):
a = True
for n in range(2, x-1):
    while n < x:
        n+=1
        if x % n == 0:
            a = False
        elif n < 2:
            a = False
        else:
            a = True
        break
    break
return a
```

If anyone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong, please let me know. A month ago I tried this and couldn't get the logic down. I think I was stumped and didn't ever ask for help... Also, how long do you think I should try to do this for before I ask for help on average?

Comment: you'd better check the definition of range(a, b, step=1), start = 2, but n==0, 1 is inside...

Comment: Don't substantively edit the question and code after people have answered, please.

Answer (score 2):

As, it has been said, you can optimize the code by just checking the odd numbers and iterating upto the sqrt of the num

```
import math
def isPrime(num):
    if(num==1):
        return False
    if(num==2):
        return True
    if(num%2==0):
        return False

    i = 3
    while(i<math.sqrt(num)+1):
        if num%i==0:
            return False
        i += 2
    return True

#do the inputs and check if isPrime
#print(isPrime(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime(number):
    for i in range(2,number,1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False

    return True
entry = int(input("Please enter the number: "))
while True:
if prime(entry):
        print ("It's a prime number. ")
        continue
    else:
        print ("It's not a prime number.. ")
        continue
```

You will entry a number then this function will give you if its a prime or not. Check the function it will solve your problem.

> **ALSO** You can upgrade the speed of your program. You know prime numbers can not be even, so you you dont have to check even numbers
>   like 4-6-8-26. So in the range function, which is (2,number) add "2"
>   end of it. like (3,number,2) then program will not check even numbers.
>
> **ALSO** a factor can not be bigger than that numbers square root. So you dont have to check all of numbers till your main number, its
>   enough to check your numbers square root. like: (2,number**0.5) that
>   means from 2 to your number square root. So double up for program
>   speed.

So the function will be:

```
def prime(number):
    for i in range(3,(number**0.5)+1),2):
        if number % i == 0:
           return False
    return True
```

The first function enough for you actually. I am working with huge numbers, so I have to upgrade the speed of my program.

Comment: better change that to (number**0.5) +1, or numbers like 49 will be incorrectly identified as a prime, as the function will only check 3-6

Answer (score 0):

using your code, and focusing on code structure:

```
def is_prime(x):
    # function contents must be indented
    if x == 0:
        return False
    elif x == 1:
        return False
    # your base cases need to check X, not n, and move them out of the loop
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(3, x-1):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    # only return true once you've checked ALL the numbers(for loop done)
    return True
```

adding some optimizations:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(3, x**(0.5)+1, 2):   # this skips even numbers and only checks up to sqrt(x)
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(x):
  for n in range(2, x-1):
    if n == 0:
    return False
    elif n == 1:
        return False
    elif n == 2:
        return True
    elif x % n == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

What you are doing wrong is , the first three if elif blocks are executed every time in the loop. So, they should be outside the for loop. Also.

```
if x%n==0:
  return True
```

It is fine. But the later

```
else:
 return True
```

is wrong because whenever the first n does not divide the x, it will return Composite. So,

```
return True
```

block must be outside the for loop.
Other optimizations can be done by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
def is_prime(n):
   if n==1:
     print("It's not a Prime number")
  for z in range(2,int(n/2)):
    if n%z==0:
      print("It's not a Prime number")
      break

  else:
    print("It's a prime number")
```

or if you want to return a boolean value

```
def is_prime(n):
   if n==1:
     return False
  for z in range(2,int(n/2)):
    if n%z==0:
      return False
      break

  else:
    return True
```